# Android why is preference changing positions automatically?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a `preferences.xml` file with some checkbox preferences, a custom time picker preference, and a custom `SeekBar` preference.  Everything works fine in my 2.2 emulator.  I've tried running it in a 1.6 emulator and every time I adjust one of the sliders(`SeekBar` preferences), or change another preference, the `SeekBar` preferences change positions.  Its like they just shuffle around.  Anybody know how I can stop this?
This keeps me from having groupings because they are always changing positions.

I have this for my preference activity:

```
public class MySettings extends PreferenceActivity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }   
}
```

This for my slider:

```
public class PreferenceSlider extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{  
    public static int maximum    = 100; 
    public static int interval   = 1;  
    private float oldValue = 50; 
    private TextView monitorBox;   
    private float beforeTouch = 50;

    public PreferenceSlider(Context context) 
    {  
        super(context); 
    }  

    public PreferenceSlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {  
        super(context, attrs); 
    }  

    public PreferenceSlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {  
        super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
    }    

    @Override 
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent)
    {     
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());      
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        params1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;   
        params1.weight  = 1.0f;         
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        params2.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;   
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        params3.gravity = Gravity.LEFT; 

        layout.setPadding(15, 5, 10, 5);   
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);      
        TextView view = new TextView(getContext());   
        view.setText(getTitle());   
        view.setTextSize(18);   
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);   
        view.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);   
        view.setLayoutParams(params1);       
        SeekBar bar = new SeekBar(getContext());   
        bar.setMax(maximum);   
        bar.setProgress((int)this.oldValue);  
        //bar.
        //bar.setLayoutParams(params2);   
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);      
        this.monitorBox = new TextView(getContext());   
        this.monitorBox.setTextSize(12);   
        this.monitorBox.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.ITALIC);   
        this.monitorBox.setLayoutParams(params3);   
        this.monitorBox.setPadding(2, 5, 0, 0);   
        this.monitorBox.setText(bar.getProgress()+"");         
        layout.addView(view);   
        layout.addView(bar);   
        layout.addView(this.monitorBox);   
        layout.setId(android.R.id.widget_frame);         
        return layout;  
    }  

    @Override 
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromTouch) 
    {      
        progress = Math.round(((float)progress)/interval)*interval;      
        if(!callChangeListener(progress)){
            seekBar.setProgress((int)this.oldValue);     
            return;     }        
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);    
        this.oldValue = progress;    
        this.monitorBox.setText(progress+"");    
        updatePreference(progress);      
        //notifyChanged(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    { 
        beforeTouch = seekBar.getProgress();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    { 
        if(beforeTouch != seekBar.getProgress())
        {
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }  

    @Override  
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray ta,int index)
    {    
        int dValue = (int)ta.getInt(index,50);       
        return validateValue(dValue); 
    }     

    @Override    
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) 
    {          
        int temp = restoreValue ? getPersistedInt(50) : (Integer)defaultValue;
        if(!restoreValue)        
            persistInt(temp);           
        this.oldValue = temp;    
    }      

    private int validateValue(int value)
    {           
        if(value > maximum)     
            value = maximum;    
        else if(value < 0)     
            value = 0;    
        else if(value % interval != 0)     
            value = Math.round(((float)value)/interval)*interval;               
        return value;      
    }         

    private void updatePreference(int newValue)
    {    
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  getEditor();  
        editor.putInt(getKey(), newValue);  
        editor.commit(); } 
    }
```

Then the `preferences.xml` is like this:

```
<com.myprogram.PreferenceSlider                  
    android:key="ringerVolume"              
    android:defaultValue="50"                
    android:title="Ringer Volume"/>

<com.myprogram.PreferenceSlider                  
    android:key="notificationVolume"                
    android:defaultValue="50"                
    android:title="Notification Volume"/>
```

Comment: Some code might help you get a better answer.

Comment: Just a thought - do you need to target 1.6? 2.2 should pretty much be the min sdk these days.

Comment: To followup on @athor's comment: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform ... 1.6 doesn't even make a blip anymore (even given their biased collection mechanism)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldnt worry about android 1.6, at least that this means that you have some dirt in your code, that is not visible for any reason in 2.2 but could be in some other versions, even newer one.

Anyways, most important here, i see that this is a question from 2011 but seems to be reopened now, and at this point, i wouldn't go on with an activity based in this code, that is quite obsolete, so having that besides it is not working perfectly, now it is the best moment, for some re-factoring.

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#addPreferencesFromResource%28int%29) **addPreferencesFromResource is deprecated since API level 11**, that means that 75% of devices look at it like as some old stuff, and some newest devices could one day even raise an error in a sort of "I told you" basis.

There is not alternative method, since what android team wants here, a couple years ago, **is not a change in the function, but a fully different approach**, using Fragments.

Specifically, you are expected to create some  [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) objects to load your preferences from a resource file.  I would recommend to do it, and don't waste time trying to fix the possible current errors on the activity. Migrating to the new approach will be easy, and you will get a much better result.

To get started, you can read some code here:

[Android Developer - Reference -  PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

Or read a complete guide here:

[Android Developer - Api Guides - UI - Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

If you go on with this, and have any further problem, don't hesitate to come back with any question and i will be glad to help you out!